# Is it possible to write parquet files with nested columns?

Tags: r, parquet

I tried to write a nested parquet file using the below

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% 
  nest(-cyl) %>% 
  arrow::write_parquet("c:/scratch/nest.parquet")
```

and I got error

```
Error in Table__from_dots(dots, schema) : 
  NotImplemented: Converting vector to arrow type struct<mpg: double, disp: double, hp: double, drat: double, wt: double, qsec: double, vs: double, am: double, gear: double, carb: double> not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
All elements of `...` must be named.
Did you want `data = c(mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb)`?
```

It seems that it's not possible to write nested-column parquet files from R.

Comment: No, it is not possible ([see data types](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md)). JSON may be a good alternative for nested data.

Comment: @Bas it can https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#nested-types

Comment: Wow, I stand corrected. Apologies. Still, I've tried doing this same thing once and couldn't get it to work. JSON worked perfectly. That apparently doesn't mean it can't be done. Good luck!